# simple jQuery file doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn jQuery and my simple function file doesn't load.
Here is the main file:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title> jQuery Exemple </title>
```

```
<p id="paragraph"> This is a paragraph </p>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/hide.js"></script>
```

and my function file:

```
$('#paragraph').click(function(){
$('#paragraph').hide();});
```

the code from the file works if i load it from chrome console. The directory and the file name are good. I searched everywere and can't find the answer.

Comment: Typo: src instead of scr in the second script line

Comment: `scr` need to be `src` here:- `<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/hide.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/hide.js"></script>
```

The path is always relative to the url displayed in the browser, if you don't provide an *absolute* path (indicated by a leading /).

Also you have a typo in the second line, it says scr instead of src.

Comment: The typo was the problem, i was looking at the code for at least one hour and didn't see it. Thank you.